# How to change the default filter operator in angular Kendo Grid

Tags: angular, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using the angular version of Kendo grid, trying to change the default filter operator for "**row**" filter mode.

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [sort]="state.sort" [filter]="state.filter"
        [sortable]="true" filterable="row" [loading]="loading" 
        (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)>
</kendo-grid>"
```

All the examples I found online is to change the default operator in "menu" filter mode, so is it possible to change the it in "**row**" filer mode?

For example in [Kendo's example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/), the default operator for date type is "is after or equal to", but I'd like to change it to "is equal to", please suggest how to do that in "**row**" mode filter.

Also how to add customized filter function for a column? 

For example, still "date" filter, I want to display the date + timestamp as the column value, but when filtering, I only want to compare the date part, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.
With kendo-grid-string-filter-**cell** you will be able to change the default operator in row filter.
With kendo-grid-string-filter-**menu** you will be able to change the default operator in menu filter.
 
Examples can be found
[here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/built-in-template/#toc-setting-the-default-filter-operator)